# Windows Server, IPv6 DNS Setting, and DNS Search Order

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I was looking through some of the DNS configs on the DC's at my new gig and noticed that ipconfig /all is listing the search order as the ipv6 local loopback as first, then the static ipv4 dns settings beneath it.  I know there's an issue when the 1st dns server is localhost and the first should be pointing outward to another DC.  Is there anything wrong with the below considering the first ip for dns is ipv6 local loopback?

```
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                    192.168.11.1
                                    127.0.0.1
```

Comment: if the AD server is acting as  DNS server then it should be pointing to itself first ::1 = localhost

Comment: Rob-d, I'm unsure about that, MS says otherwise https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff807362(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Remember that on Windows, IPv6 is mandatory (since Server 2008) while IPv4 is optional. So IPv6 addresses may appear first. Most likely the server hasn't been configured with the IPv6 address of the other DNS server.